# Why isn't my serverside callback occuring when I use 'jQuery ajax' in seaside 2.9?

Tags: jquery, ajax, seaside

I'm trying to do something like this in seaside 2.9

```
html button 
 onClick: (html jQuery ajax
  serialize: (html jQuery this);
  script: [:s | s << (s jQuery id: stratId) append: [html text: 'bing'. html break]]);
 callback: [2 inspect];
with: 'add option'.
```

and as I expect my div with stratId is getting appended but I'm not getting an inspect window in my squeak image?  What's the right way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is in the second part of the method comment of JQueryInstance>>#serializeThis:

`"Serialize the receiving element. Note that this might not work for all form
elements: (1) for check-boxes and multi-select lists Seaside internally depends on an additional hidden form element that is generated automatically, instead use #serializeThisWithHidden (2) submit-button callbacks are ignored, instead use a normal callback to trigger specific code evaluation."`

Instead put your callback code into the jQuery callback itself, aka the #script: block.